# Materialized view with replication

Tags: clickhouse

My case is a source table with Null engine and 2 its' mv with replicatedMergeTree engine. Is it possible?
I've read this man from Den Crane https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

And he described only case when source table also has the same engine with replication, so I get the question is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Null + Replicated MV.
MV tables which store data for MV are not related to MV or to source tables.

https://youtu.be/1LVJ_WcLgF8?list=PLO3lfQbpDVI-hyw4MyqxEk3rDHw95SzxJ&t=7597